# "+Other Locations" does not work after update to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, sharing, smb

I've had a few network connections set up in Nautilus under Ubuntu 19.04.

After running the upgrade to 19.10, those connections are no longer there.

Also, when I open Nautilus, now (even as root), I can see the `+ Other Locations` but whatever I enter here, it does not let me save it. The `Connect` button stays greyed out.

Clicking on the Help icon shows the format (e.g. `smb://gnome.org`) but at the bottom of the help it shows **Available Protocols** and nothing underneath it. I've installed `smbclient`, `cifs-utils`, `samba` but still nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: I am going to leave this here. Perhaps someone else runs into the same issue. I have mounted all my required shares via `fstab` and that works, but I still cannot connect to anything through Nautilus since the upgrade to 19.10